# Unable to GET Issues of Github Organization repository

Tags: curl, github, github-api

According to the [Github Docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues),
List issues for  repository has the following GET request:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues
```

---

I can access my *private* organization repo with the following curl command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token my-token-with-all-api-scopes" 
  https://api.github.com/repos/my-org/my-repo
```

However when I try to add `/issues` onto the curl command, it does not return any payload.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token my-token-with-all-api-scopes" 
  https://api.github.com/repos/my-org/my-repo/issues
```

What is wrong with my curl command to access `/issues` on the repository? As mentioned previously, I can access the repo which is private without problems.

As far as I know, I am following the github API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your command and my payload was also empty at first, but simply because I had no opened issues in that test repository. So do you have issues in the repository? If you don't the response will simply be:

```
[

]
```

Initially I thought that your problem was due to a missing `Accept` header, but it does work by default without one, although the docs ask you to be explicit in specifying one:

```
application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw+json
application/vnd.github.VERSION.text+json
application/vnd.github.VERSION.html+json
application/vnd.github.VERSION.full+json
```

Comment: So I had an issue, but it was closed! Adding `?state=all` returned open and closed issues, which resolved my problem. :)